# validating checkbox ticked with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, checkbox

Ive got some javascript im using to validate a form which works fine but I now need to add a checkbox which needs to be checked before the form submits. The name of the checkbox is terms in the html and ive managed to get it to not submit the form using the code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sendmail").click(function(){
    var valid = '';
    var isr = ' is required.';
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var mail = $("#mail").val();
    var subject = $("#subject").val();
    var country = $("#country").val();



            if( !$("#terms").is(":checked") ){
        valid += '<br />Please accept the terms and conditions.';
    }
    if (name.length<1) {
        valid += '<br />Name'+isr;
    }
    if (!mail.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
        valid += '<br />A valid Email'+isr;
    }
    if (subject.length<1) {
        valid += '<br />Website Link'+isr;
    }
    if (country.length<1) {
        valid += '<br />Country'+isr;
    }
    if (valid!='') {
        $("#response").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#response").html("Error:"+valid);
                    setTimeout('$("#response").fadeOut("slow")',4000);
    }
    else {
        var datastr ='name=' + name + '&mail=' + mail + '&subject=' + subject + '&country=' + country;
        $("#response").css("display", "block");
        $("#response").html("<img src='http://infashionation.com/female/images/response.jpg'>");
        $("#response").fadeIn("slow");
        setTimeout("send('"+datastr+"')",2000);
    }
    return false;
});
```

The problem is it now doesnt submit regardless of whether box is checked or not.

Ive been searched for some information to help me with this for a while but no luck so thought I would ask here to see if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an extra exclamation point after the valid variable. I suggest also using a javascript debugger.

```
if (valid!='') {
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing curly brace for your .ready function.

Comment: Sorry yes the }); is there I didnt copy it over when posting one here. The form validation works for the input text but not for the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you've closed the $(document).ready() function.  You close the sendmail click function, but not the main function.  I think the tail end of your code should look like this:
        }
    return false;
    }); // close sendmail function
    }); // close document.ready

If that happened because of copying it to SO, then disregard this, but if this is in your code, your browser will probably not do a thing and appear not to react to the JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry yes the }); is there I didnt copy it over when posting one here. The form validation works for the input text but not for the checkbox.